# CloudFormation: How to use AWS::AccountId in Mappings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have a mapping that looks like this:

```
Mappings:
  AccountToParams:
    aws-1234567890:
      sshSecurityGroup: sg-abcedf12
```

And I'd like to retrieve my variables by AccountId, but this doesn't get past the "validation" step

```
SecurityGroups:
    - !FindInMap [AccountToParams, !Sub "aws-${AWS::AccountId}", sshSecurityGroup]
```

Error is

```
16/08/2017, 16:36:18 - Template contains errors.: Template error: 
every Fn::FindInMap object requires three parameters, 
the map name, map key and the attribute for return value
```

The goal is to have some configuration driven by the account (hence environment) this is run under. And I can't seem to use the accountId as the key in the mapping, otherwise AWS isn't happy because it doesn't contain alphanumeric chars

Comment: You do not *a* mapping. You have four (4) mappings in that YAML document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the map to:

```
Mappings:
  AccountToParams:
    "1234567890":
      sshSecurityGroup: sg-abcedf12
```

and use `!Ref` instead of `!Sub`:

```
SecurityGroupIds:
    - !FindInMap [AccountToParams, !Ref "AWS::AccountId", sshSecurityGroup]
```

Use [FN::Join](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) to prepend "aws" string to account ID if that's required further down the stack.

Comment: perfect, simple and concise

Comment: You dont get this error for using number as map key? Template format error: [/Mappings/TargetAzMap] map keys must be strings; received numeric [xxxxx] instead

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
Mappings: 

  AccountToParams:
    "123456789012":
      sshSecurityGroup: sg-abcdef12
  
Resources: 
 
      SecurityGroups: !FindInMap 
            - AccountToParams
            - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
            - sshSecurityGroup
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).